# Loop with "Select Cases" combined

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have attempted to combine a simple loop code and select cases to return a desired user result (I am aware the code is incorrect). Within column J I have a series of years ranging from 2012 to 2017 dependant on the year in column J I wish to cut the data from column U to AG and paste it, in its correct place.

The code I have come up with is below;

```
Sub Move_data()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("J1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells((LR), 10))

For x = 2 To LR Step 1
Select Case Range("J" & x).Value2
        Case 2012
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("AH" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2013
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("AU" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2014
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("BH" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2015
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("BU" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2016
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("CH" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Case 2017
            Range("BU" & x).Cut
            Range("IH" & x).Paste
            Range("U" & x, ":CG" & x).Cut
            Range("CU" & x).PasteSpecial
            ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1

           End Select

             x = x + 1
            Else
            End If
            Next x


            End Sub
```

Also I have a feeling it may not be time efficient to loop through each line as there is over 1000 lines within the file, It may be quicker to sort and select all the same years and move the data all at once. (However I am unsure of how to do this)

Any help in code adaptation or guidance of the best way to achieve this would be much appreciated! I have attached a picture for guidance of what I am trying to achieve. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While this won't do exactly what you're looking for, it will give you an idea on how to get started using tables. This will detect unique values in your table (instead of setting your case examples) and then try to track it through. You'll have to convert your data source to a table (`listobject`) and there are a few other things which you will need to modify (have tried to highlight them with comments. Have a look through the code and feel free to ask any questions if it's of use.

**Data source (table)**

[image: Data source]

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub tableLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer: Dim NoRow As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim c

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' first we will sort the table into order on year
    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        ' Change the Range to match your table and year column)
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Project Year]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Get unique values in project year and put into array

    With tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
        .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    End With
    i = 0
    For Each c In tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i)
        arr(i) = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next c

    ' Change this loop for however you want the output to be
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
        With tbl
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr(i)
            .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        End With
        With ws
            NoRow = i
            .Cells(NoRow, 5) = arr(i)
            .Cells(NoRow, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            On Error Resume Next
            .ShowAllData
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next i

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

In my hasty look at your code it looks like only the `Range(...).PasteSpecial` line differs between the different cases. You could eliminate the `Select Case` structure and instead create an array that holds the columns for the `PasteSpecial`: `cols = {"AH", "AU", "BH", "BU", "CH", "CU"}`. Then you could select the column by `TheCol = cols(year-2011)`.

Another way: since the columns are regularly spaced (13 apart) you could go by column number: `col_num = 13*(year-2011) + 21`. Then use something like `Range.Cells(x, col_num)`.

Hope that helps